# Seperate value of a specific column with "," delimiter in Oracle using "Regular Expression"

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql, regular-expression

I have a table with below structure:

```
create table CUSTOMER_INFO
(
  cust_id      NUMBER,
  cust_name    VARCHAR2(50),
  cust_address VARCHAR2(50)
)
```

Example Data :

```
cust_id   |  cust_name |  cust_address
------------------------------------------
  1       |     A      |  Tehran,Tehran  
  2       |     B      |  Rasht,Tehran    
  3       |     C      |  Minsk,Tehran
```

I want to have this output:

```
cust_id   |  cust_name |  cust_address
------------------------------------------
  1       |     A      |  Tehran
  2       |     B      |  Tehran    
  2       |     B      |  Rasht
  3       |     C      |  Minsk
  3       |     C      |  Tehran
```

what I've written so far is this :

```
select distinct cust_id, 
                cust_name, 
                address
  from (select distinct cust_id,
                        cust_name,
                        regexp_substr(cust_address, '[^,]+', 1, level) address
          from customer_info 
        connect by regexp_substr(cust_address, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
order by cust_id
```

I want to know if there is better way of writing this query and Will this solution produce false result ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain your logic.  In your example, all of your cust-id have two values in cust_address.  You show that you want to return one of those for cust_id=1, but both for the other cust_id.  That said, your data model is fundamentally broken.  Those comma-separated values in a single column mean you don't even meet First Normal Form.  Get your data model correct (Third Normal Form) and your problem disappears.

Comment: Cust_id=1 has only one unique Address which is 'Tehran' so I need to have one record which is cust_id=1 , cust_address='Tehran'. Cust_id=2 has two unique Addresses which are 'Rasht' and 'Tehran' so I need to have two records for cust_id=2. The point is that there might be more than two unique addresses for each cust_id for instance there might be cust_id=10 with address column "Tehran,Minsk,Rasht" and now , I need to have three records for this cust_id.this table has been given to us and we were not in charge of modeling the data unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an approach makes sure you don't get *too many duplicates* as your query does (so you removed them with a `distinct` in line #4; without it, you'd get 12 rows as a result):

```
SQL> with customer_info (cust_id, cust_name, cust_address) as
  2    (select 1, 'A', 'Tehran,Tehran' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'B', 'Rasht,Tehran'  from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'C', 'Minsk,Tehran'  from dual
  5    )
  6  select --distinct      --> use DISTINCT to get result you want
  7         cust_id,
  8         cust_name,
  9         regexp_substr(cust_address, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) cust_address
 10  from customer_info cross join
 11    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                        connect by level <= regexp_count(cust_address, ',') + 1
 13                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14  order by cust_id;

   CUST_ID C CUST_ADDRESS
---------- - ----------------------------------------------------
         1 A Tehran
         1 A Tehran
         2 B Rasht
         2 B Tehran
         3 C Minsk
         3 C Tehran

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

However, as you want to have only one `1-A-Tehran` combination, `distinct` in line #6 has to be uncommented.